# geting each failed results in if multiple conditions

Tags: shell, if-statement, scripting

I have below conditions . IF all conditions are meet then it passes. If it fails then need to know which condition makes it to fail ?

```
if [[ -z “$pas” ]] && [[ $dd_check_pass == “pass” ]] && [[ $asmresultcheck == “pass” ]];
then
zzz=Passed;
else
zzz=Failed;
aaa=”Due to unknown process running”
fi
```

Comment: You have "smart" quotes in your code, not plain double quotes: make sure you're using a text editor and not a word processor when working on your code.

Comment: You'd have to write nested `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know which condition failed, then you need to act on each one individually:

```
if [[ -n "$pas" ]]; then
    aaa="pas variable is not empty"
    zzz=Failed
elif [[ $dd_check_pass != "pass" ]]; then
    aaa="dd_check_pass variable is not pass"
    zzz=Failed
elif [[ $asmresultcheck != "pass" ]]; then
    aaa="asmresultcheck variable is not pass"
    zzz=Failed
else
    zzz=Passed
fi
```

Comment: I did it using a case so that it gives me which condition has failed.

Comment: I'm curious how you coded that. Can you provide it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```html
pass=""
dd_check_pass="pass"
asmresultcheck="pass"
var=pass
case $var in 
pass)
if [[ -z  $pasrep ]]
then
echo "\n"
echo "users condition Passed"
else
echo "\n"
echo "users condition failed"
fi
;&

dd_check_pass)
if [[ $dd_check_pass == "pass" ]]
then
echo "\n"
echo "cluster check passed"
else
echo "\n"
echo "cluster check failed"
fi 
;&

asmresultcheckin)
if [[ $asmresultcheck == "pass" ]]
then
echo "\n"
echo "asm check passed"
else
echo "\n"
echo "asm check failed"
fi
;&
esac
echo "\n"
echo "Check the above result. If all are passed then proceed with duedeligence or else don't proceed. Do you wish to proceed (y/n)?"
read ans
if [ $ans == y ]
then
echo "\n"
echo "passed"
else
echo "\n"
echo "failed"
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some explanation to your code. here are some rules on answers - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer